# Is there a way to use WordPress Menus for in-page sub navigation?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, sidebar

I want to make this question clear: I want to use the "Appearance > Menus" section to manage the main navigation and also be able to pull the first level sub nav to be placed in-page sidebar (cherry pick, parts of the menu). I do NOT want to use `wp_list_pages` or the like. I want to be able to manage both aspects of the navigation from "Appearance > Menus".

Is there an easy way to do this with out writing my own walker?

Answer (score 1):

@alibaster's solution works, but does require multiple nav menus. If your goal is to have all menu items managed from a single menu, you could use absolute positioning depending on your layout:

```
.menu-item {
    position:relative;
}
.menu-item .sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100px;
}
```

You can use the 'walker' argument to customize the output of your wp_nav_menu call:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new menu in Appearance > Menus and display it anywhere you would like using `<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Project Nav' )); ?>`.  You would of course need to change 'Project Nav' your new menu's name.

The full info on that function can be found in the codex here: [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

For example, if you have a menu named Sub Nav Menu you would use:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Sub Nav Menu' )); ?>`

Just drop that entire php line in your template file where you would like the menu to appear, and don't forget the change the name of the menu to your new menu's name.

I hope this is what you were looking for.  If not, let us know and we'll get you going in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, but not quite what i'm looking for .. I already have a "primary nav" menu setup .. now on sub pages I want to reference that menu and cherry pick just the sub pages in the sidebar for the inner pages

Comment: No problem.  I guess I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Put this little snippet wherever you want. I added an "if" condition so it doesn't show any code if you have't assigned a menu for it yet.

```
<?php 
if ( has_nav_menu( 'sub-menu' ) ) {
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location'  => 'sub-menu',
)); 
} ?>
```

The name "sub-menu" can be changed to whatever you like if you want to keep adding these. More on it on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question completely - and even though this thread is old. I want to know if you have had any success in solving this issue.

I see this issue ALL the time. I have viewed hundreds of great Wordpress themes, really great. But none of them are solving the "Sidebar menu" in a good way. list_pages.. are good, but there are some huge benefits of making the "active parent" having to show the menu in the sidebar - and not only in the top.

I will keep researching on this. One way is to use wp_nav_menu twice, one for the top and one for the sidebar - with the same "Menu". But using css to make hide the top-level items hidden that is not currently active. Not the best way - but still.. it is a way ;)

Comment: That is currently what we are doing, is using wp_nav_menu twice .. we use CSS to hide the submenus, etc ... we've also used custom classes to denote sidebar-only and main-only links as well (these can be added per link in the Menu editor) ... another way was to simply create two menus and manage two separately